# try_files along with filename in nginx

Tags: nginx

How come http://192.168.10.20/greet show's "Hello User" instead of displaying thumb.png even thought first match has file in root folder. Is that it will first trying to match with name's and then the content in try_files locations.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 192.168.10.20;
  root /sites/demo;
  try_files /thumb.png /greet;
  location = /greet {
    return 200 "Hello User";
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me to understand this.

Comment: The URL `/greet` is processed by the `location = /greet` block. Your `try_files` statement is in a different location context, and will only be used to process the request if no other location is selected.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith, Sorry, i don't see option to accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx [chooses a location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) to process a request.

It's not well documented, but the `server` block is also a location context and will be chosen if no other location is selected to process the request.

So you have two separate locations in your configuration, `location = /greet` which is selected if the URI matches `/greet` and the one containing `try_files /thumb.png /greet;` if the URI does not match `/greet`.